# Search raw text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to search a text_word from raw text using jQuery.

```
$("#s:regex('text_word')").each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#s1');

});

<div id="s">raw text here</a>

<div id="s1"></a>
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Your question is unclear, please add some more information like what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: I have some raw text in #s and I want to select certain words from #s and appendTo #s1

Answer (score 1):

Your request is not clear; if you need to filter your div by text
you could try with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("div:contains('Text to search')").each(function(index) {
     alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: adding an alert(fIn) pops up the message [object Object]

Comment: It returns a jQuery object, you need to iterate over it.